# How to execute a command: SET IDENTITY_INSERT <table> ON on SQL Server table from Spark/Databricks?

Tags: sql-server, apache-spark, azure-databricks

I have been able to read/write from Databricks into SQL Server table using JDBC driver. However this time I have to execute a command before I write to a SQL Server.
I need to execute this command on SQL server: SET IDENTITY_INSERT <sqlserver_table_name> ON
How to do this from Databricks ? Any help/pointers are appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't do this with the JDBC Spark Connector (or the [SQL Server Spark Connector](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/spark/connector?view=sql-server-ver15)), but it's trivial when using JDBC directly in Scala or Java.  When using JDBC directly you have explicit control of the session, and you can issue multiple batches in the same session, or multiple statements in the same batch.  EG

```
%scala

import java.util.Properties
import java.sql.DriverManager

val jdbcUsername =  dbutils.secrets.get(scope = "kv", key = "sqluser")
val jdbcPassword = dbutils.secrets.get(scope = "kv", key = "sqlpassword")
val driverClass = "com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver"

// Create the JDBC URL without passing in the user and password parameters.
val jdbcUrl = s"jdbc:sqlserver://xxxxxx.database.windows.net:1433; . . ."

val connection = DriverManager.getConnection(jdbcUrl, jdbcUsername, jdbcPassword)
val stmt = connection.createStatement()
val sql = """

SET IDENTITY_INSERT <sqlserver_table_name> ON

"""

stmt.execute(sql)

//run additional batches here with IDENTITY_INSERT ON
    
connection.close()
```

And you can always use the Spark Connector to load a staging table, then use JDBC to run a stored procedure or ad-hoc SQL batch to load the staging data into the target table.

Comment: Thanks David. Yes, I used a JDBC connector and it worked.

val sql = "SET IDENTITY_INSERT <sqlserver_table> ON;insert into <sqlserver_table>"
stmt.execute(sql)